# Spring MVC model access in jsp failed

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven, model

i am new to Spring. I created a maven project in eclipse to test Spring MVC by resembling the mvc-basic example from Spring example SVN repository. when i tried to retrieve model values in jsp, the jsp just displayed ${model attribute name}, not the model attribute value.

Do I miss anything making Spring failed to retrieve model value?

Below are the details:

code:  controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestAction {

@RequestMapping(value="/test" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String returnHelloWorld(Model model)
{
    ObjectTest objectTest=new ObjectTest();
    objectTest.setName("heng");
    model.addAttribute(objectTest);
    return "/test/start";
}
 }
```

code JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
     hello ${objectTest.name}  
</body>
</html>
```

When running it on the server (tomcat 6)
the page displayed like

> hello ${objectTest.name}

but should be

> hello heng

POM.XML file:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>heng.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>firststudy</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
     <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
       <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>



  </dependencies>



</project>
```

here is the snapshot

[image]

> Note:

I created a normal eclipse dynamic project and create the same controller , jsp and other component. and the jsp can retrieve the model value successfully.
here is the snapshot of the project and jars.

the difference is that this project has springframework.web.servlet jar
while the maven project has sprinng-webmvc jar

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the reason for the problem is EL is not enabled

to enable EL, i changed the web.xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

 <web-app>
 ....
 </web-app>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for this. It really save my time.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to output data in a jsp with JSTL is using

```
<c:out value="${objectTest.name}" />
```

Another remark: I find personnaly more clear the use of ModelAndView:

```
@Controller
public class TestAction {

  @RequestMapping(value="/test" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView returnHelloWorld()
  {
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/test/start");
      ObjectTest objectTest=new ObjectTest();
      objectTest.setName("heng");
      modelAndView.addObject("myObject", objectTest);
      return modelAndView;
  }
}
```

You can then output the value in your jsp with:

```
<c:out value="${myObject.name}" />
```

Comment: Hi , i also tried <c:out value="${myObject.name}" /> and the JSP still prints ${myObject.name}.   And i also tried @ResponseBody to return a json object. and the JSP can capture the json object.